# Is possible to use a Micro SIM in iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, sim

I want to use my old iPhone 3GS, but don't want to pay another plan for the occasional use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need an adapter [like this one](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.41355) to make it fit, but it should work.